# Material UI theme.palette.type typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm a beginner at Material UI and TypeScript.
ps: I apologize if I have incorrectly formatted the question, the first question on stackoverflow.

[image: code]
[image: error]

Comment: Welcome! It always helps to provide some context when posting a question and not just screenshots. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In case of code, it is preferable to provide it in [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) or in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), rather than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` only accepts the literal strings `'light'` and `'dark'`. That is [different to the general string type](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript).

The initial value you provide to `useState` is a literal type, but Typescript widens the return type of function expressions. In other words, `mode` is of type string.

`useState` is a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and you can pass in the types to prevent the type widening

```js
const [mode, setMode] = useState<'light' | 'dark'>('dark')
```